# Schedule kill of port connections

Tags: connection, service, kill, vss

We use VSS in our company, but have numerous cases were we can't backup the databases as users have locked them.

Is there a way to schedule a kill of all connetions to the source safe service. Or any Rekommandation?

Regards,
Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, stopping the server service seems a bit extreme.

You can disconnect network connections in Computer Management by navigating to "Shared Folders" then "Open Files" and right clicking the connection. This is a graphical app and isn't any good for running from a script, but I'm sure I have seem a command line app that does this and can be scripted. However it's name has slipped my mind :-(

Some Googling found http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783450(WS.10).aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290585, which describe some rather clunky ways to do this. I'm sure there's an app that does it in one go.

I actually wrote a command line app to close connections back in the NT4 days. If you want it (and the source) I'd be happy to oblige, but as I say I'm sure there is an MS applet that does it.

JR

PS Aha! The applet I was thinking of is openfiles.exe.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with our time and billing system database.  People would forget to exit the program or log off on a fairly consistent basis.  Our solution was to force workstations to reboot nightly prior to the backup being run.

Essentially, we organized our computers in Active Directory by creating folders.  We then created a wrapper file that runs the psshutdown tool from SysInternals (now Microsoft) to remotely shutdown all of the computers in a particular folder on our AD structure.  It works pretty good.

If somebody has a valid need to keep a machine on overnight, such as a long running process, all we have to do is move their computer out of the Workstations folder and then put it back when they are finished.

Answer (score 0):

net stop server /y

will force shutdown the server process serving up the fileshare where the vss library lives.

i'd caution you on this because if the client is writing at the time you do this, you will get a corruption.

If you can be confident that everyone's out of the office and not using it, you should be safe enough.

net start server will bring the service back online after the backup.

M.